# Is it possible to have a foreign key that is NOT NULL pointing to no row in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I have a table storing comments on a service, the table looks like something like this:

```
Comment table
---------------------------
comment_id (auto-increment integer, primary key)
comment (string)
email (string)
```

Now, a member system is added to the system, a table storing the member information that looks something like this:

```
Member table
---------------------
member_id (auto-increment integer, primary key)
.... some other member info .....
email (string, unique)
```

A member can leave multiple comment, while one comment can only be left by one member, or it can be left by a non-member (i.e. email not exist in member table). I know I can handle it by opening a new table (`member_comment_pair`), but I am curious if there is a way I can set up a foreign key on `email` in comment table, such that it allows `email` that may not be able to find a match in member table?

`NOTE:` I am using MySQL, but in case it is not possible in MySQL but allowed in other type of DB system, I would also like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No self respecting database system will allow such a thing, since it defeats the entire purpose of having foreign keys.
You see, a foreign key is the database way to ensure [relational integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity).
A short explanation would be that data in the referencing column can't exists if it doesn't exists in the referenced column.

Once you allow a loop hole like you are describing you might as well throw the foreign key out the window.

I've seem some strange things that MySql allows (Like it's strange group by behavior) but if it will allow a broken foreign key to exists it should not be called a relational database.

Having said that, You can choose one of at least 3 possible solutions:

1. Create a dummy record in the `Member` table that "orphan" records in the `Comment` table would be linked to it.
2. Allow null values in the `Comment` table's `email` column.
3. Remove the foreign key completely.

I would choose (and have done before when needed) solution number one. Create a record in the `Member` table (have it's display name as "guest" or whatever) and link all the orphan comments to it.

Comment: The email in comment is for future identification when the guest decided to become a member, so it cannot be set to point to a dummy member. It cannot be null as the email is also used for some follow up action to the comment. I want the function of foreign key such that the member cannot be deleted when there are comments connected to it. So it seems the 3 solutions are not applicable in my case......

Comment: Then don't link comments and members by email, link them by member id. Once you do that, you have all the benefits of a foreign key and you leave your email column in the comments free to use. If the comment is written by a logged in member, auto-fill his email column for him. If it's written by a guest, let them fill it in with whatever address they want.